# Alternating Background Image on Load

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my rails 4 app.

I've just given up on trying to integrate the bootstrap carousel into my page. (it pushes my text to the next container and doesn't resize the images with my styling).

I have two background images. My objective is to have those rotate from the time the page is loaded, on a timer.

My css has a background image, with text over the top of it and a darkened background over the top of bottom half of the background image so that the text is more clearly readable.  I don't want the text to change as the background image changes.

I have the following css and html. I've tried to use js that people have set up for their various events, but nothing is working with this structure.

Does anyone know how to alternate a background image?

HTML:

```
<div class= "containerfluid">
  <div class="collagecontainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class= "row">
          <div class="col-md-12"> 
            <div class="module">
              <header>
                <h1 style="letter-spacing:2px"><br><br><br>Constant header remains the same</h1>
                <h3>constant tagline remains the same</h3>
                </header>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.module {
  background: image-url('glowc.jpg');
  background-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

.module > header {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.module > header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px) ;
  filter: blur(4px) ;
}
.module > header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}
.module > header > h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.module > header > h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left:15%;
  padding-right:15%;
  padding-top:20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  color:#E8DA0C;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I would like to have the background-image in .module to alternate between glowc.jpg with glowp.jpg. All the rest should remain the same.

JS:

I'm trying to figure this out. I'm up to this point but getting lost and confused.

```
var images = [
do i put my alternate image here?
 ];

 var index = 0;

 setInterval(change_up, 1000);

 function change_up(){

     index = (index + 1 < images.length) ? index + 1 : 0;

   $('.block').fadeOut(300, function(){

     $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+ images[index] + ')')

     $(this).fadeIn(300);

   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the class and URLs for images.

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/maxlipsky/ua337onq/1/

```
var images = [
"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/a/a6/Bender_Rodriguez.png", "http://theinfosphere.org/images/thumb/4/43/Bender.png/180px-Bender.png"
 ];

 var index = 0;

 setInterval(change_up, 2000);

 function change_up(){

     index = (index + 1 < images.length) ? index + 1 : 0;

   $('.module').fadeOut(300, function(){

     $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+ images[index] + ')')

     $(this).fadeIn(300);

   });
 }
```